# Problem with router-view duplicating the components

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Recently changed from laravel routing to Vue Router. Whenever I'd insert the `<router-view></router-view>` in any part of the file below, it'll duplicate the component which the router routes to (i.e. it will duplicate the div part of the component and insert it in the sidebar.vue file) .

For demonstration of the problem: [image: before insertion of the router-view] vs [image: after insertion]

SideBar.vue file is

```
<template>
  <aside class="container_sidebar">
        <nav id="sidebar">
            <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                <li class="active">
                    <router-link to="/nghome">Home</router-link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <router-link to="/ngsongs">All Songs</router-link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <router-link to="/ngalbums">Albums</router-link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <router-link to="/ngartists">Artists</router-link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </aside>
    
</template>
```

My Router.js file is

```
import NightingaleHome from "./components/NightingaleHome";
import NightingaleSongs from "./components/NightingaleSongs";
import NightingaleArtists from "./components/NightingaleArtists";
import NightingaleAlbum from "./components/NightingaleAlbum";
import MusicUpload from "./components/MusicUpload";

export const routes = [{
        path: "/home",
        component: NightingaleHome,
        name: "home",
    },
    {
        path: "/ngsongs",
        component: NightingaleSongs,
        name: "All Songs",
    },
    {
        path: "/ngartists",
        component: NightingaleArtists,
        name: "All Artists",
    },
    {
        path: "/ngalbums",
        component: NightingaleAlbum,
        name: "All Album",
    },
    {
        path: "/fileupload",
        component: MusicUpload,
        name: "Music File Upload",
    },
];
```

And my App.js file is

```
require('./bootstrap');

import { routes } from "./router";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuesax from 'vuesax';
import { BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue';

// Import Bootstrap an BootstrapVue CSS files (order is important)
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

// Make BootstrapVue available throughout your project
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
    // Optionally install the BootstrapVue icon components plugin
Vue.use(IconsPlugin)

import 'vuesax/dist/vuesax.css' //Vuesax styles
Vue.use(Vuesax, {
    // options here
})

window.Vue = require('vue').default;

Vue.component('music-player', require('./components/MusicPlayer.vue').default);
Vue.component('music-upload', require('./components/MusicUpload.vue').default);
Vue.component('upload-progress', require('./components/UploadProgress.vue').default);
Vue.component('nightingale-songs', require('./components/NightingaleSongs.vue').default);
Vue.component('nightingale-album', require('./components/NightingaleAlbum.vue').default);
Vue.component('nightingale-artist', require('./components/NightingaleArtists.vue').default);
Vue.component('side-bar', require('./components/SideBar.vue').default);
Vue.component('edit-songs', require('./components/EditSongs.vue').default);
Vue.component('nightingale-home', require('./components/NightingaleHome.vue').default);

Vue.use(VueRouter);

let router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes
});

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,

});
```

I don't have App.vue file because currently I don't need it. Any solutions?

Comment: Please, share your VueRouter configuration. Also, I don't see any `<router-view>` in the file you've shared.

Comment: Edited to include router.js and app.js file. Also `<router-view>` isn't included because it causes the main problem, 1st pic is without and 2nd pic is with `<router-view>` added to the SideBar.vue file. Hope I've cleared

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there help you but for similar issue, I delete the root path in my router file ( path : "/" component: App).
I think the nativ root is already charged so you don't have to built-it.

Comment: The OP is probably a senior by now.